# Will installing Ubuntu harm my computer?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, wubi

I installed Ubuntu using wubi on hp dv6-6135dx.

When I boot into Ubuntu, I get a black screen.

The wireless light turns blue after a while, meaning Ubuntu has loaded the driver, but the screen stays turned off.

When I first booted into Wubi I got a black screen with white screen with text that said

> generating locales... done. Warning: Not compatible with locale
>   us.uTF8....

It stayed stuck at this screen, so I hard shut down the computer after about a half hour.

Now wubi won't boot. I'm considering dual-booting, but will Ubuntu actually start? Can Ubuntu mess up my Windows 7 installation?

Comment: Unless you play with partitions, Ubuntu is harmless to all other operating systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Ubuntu works on a LiveCD, it will likely work when you dual boot. Ubuntu cannot mess your Windows installation up unless you do it incorrectly.

To install it correctly, resize the Windows partition from within Windows 7. Do this by using the device manager (right click My Computer, click device manager, and then use the disk management section).

When you boot the LiveCD and go to the installation screen, it will offer to install alongside Windows 7. Use that option and you should have no further issues, and it will offer to boot Windows on startup.

---

If you have a Windows 7 DVD, and later want to restore the boot loader for Window 7, you can also do that, but you wouldn't be able to load Ubuntu in that case.

---

Ubuntu cannot harm your ***computer*** btw.

Comment: Is there any way to install Ubuntu without modifying the windows bootloader?

Comment: @William: Yes, but you wouldn't be able to boot Ubuntu, unless you can find a GRUB2 for Windows :).

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 physical different hard drives you can install a boot loader on each and change the boot device on your computer's BIOS every time you want to boot one or the other, on the same disk with 2 systems only 1 boot loader can exist.

Comment: Use VirtualBox or Vmware to create a virtual PC and install Ubuntu on virtual PC. It will be completely safe and more comfortable for you.

Comment: A hard disk costs less then 20 dollars/euros/(what ever), if you are afraid of messing up your windows partitions you can always get a 2nd disk, plug it in, install Ubuntu in it and set it as boot device in your BIOS, when you are comfortable playing around with dual boots, grubs, resizings, etc you can always keep the 2nd disk as a backup solution.

Comment: @BrunoPereira: the HP dv6 is a single hard drive laptop :). I've got a dv7 - so I can play around with the dual HDD solution, but he can't :).

Comment: @RolandTaylor Sure he can, for 25 euros/dollars/(whatever) he can buy a USB external one, play around with Ubuntu, when he sees that its much better then Windows he will remove Windows from his main and use the USB external as a backup solution! *Eats cookies*

Comment: @RolandTaylor My gf has a dv7 also, I am sure it allows external device booting ;)

Comment: @BrunoPereira: rofl :D

Comment: @RolandTaylor I'm not saying your answer is wrong, actually its very good, but if the user wants to install Ubuntu and be able to double boot there are also other options (even a USB pen will do!)

Answer (score 1):

The dual boot option will work for you, but there are a few considerations.

First, is that you have to resize your hard drive partitions, which, if you've got a newish machine, shouldn't be too challenging.  The windows disk manager can be used, but I recommend using an application to handle it, like Partition Magic ($) or GParted (Free).

Next, GRUB is installed by default, but should you choose to roll back, you may need to fix the Master Boot Record in Windows Safe Mode.  That can be a pain, but ultimately it's fixed quickly.

Finally, you may still end up with driver issues.  Wubi isn't new, but it has it's challenges with newer hardware, as you know.  This is less of an issue with the traditional installation since there isn't another layer that the OS has to use to access the hardware.  The more generic drivers will get you through.

Ultimately, to answer your question, it won't hurt your computer, but I'd make sure I have a recent backup and Win7 restore partition or install dvd handy should anything happen.

Comment: Do you mean wubi?

Comment: Yea, but re-reading your post, that's what caused the issue.  My apologies.  I'll update my response.