# I'm scared, help me

Tags: system-installation

I really want to install Ubuntu, but I'm scared that my computer may break. I intend to overwrite Windows so that Ubuntu is the only OS left. I tried this once before but it said it would take a long time. How long would that be for a 128GB SSD? Also, what are the chances of this installation breaking my system?

I hope I don't sound stupid...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: @bain nope. I know how. I just wanna know the chances of it rendering my system unusable.

Comment: use virtual machine then.

Comment: To clarify, it said that it would "take a long time" to reformat the drive to suit it for Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will installing Ubuntu harm my computer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86141/will-installing-ubuntu-harm-my-computer)

Answer (score 4):

You can just try Ubuntu without uninstalling Windows in first time. Play with this configuration for weeks and if you are happy with, just full install with overwrite Windows (or keep the dual boot if you want, it's not a problem).

The "speed" of the installation depend of your hard drive (TPM). But it's never more than 30-40 min.

You cant break your computer. You can allways install another OS when you want ; just need to use a disc or a USB key for.

Hope i helping u :p

Comment: Yeah, but what do I do if GRUB appears one day with that "minimal bash-like line editing is supported" error?

Comment: Nevermind i found that out actually http://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

Comment: i can also just type "exit" to boot into Windows if I'm dual-booting I think (atleast in my experience :) )

Comment: @It'sWillem yes of course, but if you install correctly Ubunty you shouldn't have a GRUB error. If you are someone who not play with partition its "rare" to have a grub issue (not impossible!). Meanwhile, we still here for helping you if you have some problems ;-)